# Chrome keeps crashing; throwing an error "Error code: RESULT_CODE_UNINSTALL_USER_CANCEL"

Tags: google-chrome

While working on Macbook Pro(2019), macOS Catalina (10.15.6); from past two days, Chrome started crashing outrageously.

Especially whenever Gmail/Youtube is opened - it keeps showing "Error code: RESULT_CODE_UNINSTALL_USER_CANCEL". I have already uninstalled the Chrome completely and reinstalled (Current & Previous version - 84.0.4147.105). Even all the plugins were removed; but I keep getting this error message.

Please help. Thanks

[image]